# how to get usernames from a different table using the keys i got from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have two tables in database

1. users{id, username, email, etc...}
2. photos{photo_description, uploaded_on, uploaded_by,etc...}

each time the page loads, i display all the images and details except username

now i need to get the usernames of the uploaders of the photos i have in photos db, i have only the ids of the users...

i tried to join the tables, but i am worried that there are more than 10k users, but hardly hundreds of them uploaded pics.

help with sql query to get the result quickly

Comment: joins are why people use relational databases. 10k users is **NOTHING** for a database.

Comment: So what's your current query? And what's the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Join is the right way

```
Select p.*, u.username from photos p join users u on (u.id = p.uploaded_by)
```

Then you can get all photo-cols and the corresponding username to this photo.

(Sorry for format, writing from mobile phone)

Comment: well thanks... :) i figured out this one for my problem using inner join....

SELECT * FROM photos inner join users on users.id=photos.updated_by

thank you all :)